# Code getting stuck loading first page in multiple url webscrape request

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I've written a small code to practice getting elements from multiple websites and put them in a csv file on my desktop. However, every time I run the code it gets stuck on the first URL after having recorded the information in the csv file created on my desktop. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Here's the code

```
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

chromedriver_path = "/Users/kylecastellanos/Documents/chromedriver_mac64"
service = Service(chromedriver_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

# List of URLs to scrape
urls = [
    "https://www.sothebys.com/en/buy/auction/2020/impressionist-modern-art-evening-sale/wifredo-lam-omi-obini",
    "https://www.sothebys.com/en/buy/auction/2023/contemporary-discoveries-9/untitled-10?locale=en",
    # Add more URLs here
]

# Write data to CSV file
with open('/Users/kylecastellanos/Desktop/output.csv', mode='w') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['url', 'title', 'text']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for url in urls:
        timeout = 10
        try:
            driver.get(url)
            print(driver.title)

            element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="placebidtombstone"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]')))
            print(element.text)

            writer.writerow({'url': url, 'title': driver.title, 'text': element.text})
            
            # Move on to the next URL
            continue

        except TimeoutException:
            continue

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error occurred for URL: {url}")
            print(e)
```

Not sure how to fix this, I consulted with some more experienced friends and they said to add a wait time and continue command, but that hasn't resolved the issue either.